# Cannot save GPX files in ArcGIS Online and make them to perdure in My Content

Tags: arcgis-online, gpx

I am trying to use a sample.gpx containing 2,913 records and lat, lon, name, cmt and type per record, but uploading it into ArcGIS Online (Public account) and works fine at the very beginning, in essence I can see my points displayed in the map and/or change the symbology and so on, but after Saving or Signing Out -still I haven't isolated the cause- when I move back to the map for editing, I cannot see the points displayed any more! no matter how long I wait for the map to load (in case it is a server response issue) and I have to re-upload them again as a new layer, otherwise I don't know how to bring them back.

It is very frustrating starting over and over again, any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the web map?